# Como inserir pagina .php dentro de um elemento HTML com JS

Tags: php, javascript

Olá, eu estou chamando uma pagina `.php` com o método `load`, o problema dele é que quando eu dou `include` em algo que deveria ficar desta forma `include './dir/arquivo.php';` depois que o `load` carrega a pagina o `include` **é obrigado** a ficar desta forma para funcionar `../dir/arquivo.php`, além de alguns elementos não funcionarem.

Porem quando eu uso apenas o `include` direto, sem JS para chamar, funciona perfeitamente, eu gostaria de uma forma para fazer o JS(*ou até mesmo o PHP*) executar `include 'arquivo.php'`(*ou alguma forma que não fique `bugado`*) quando o botão é pressionado.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $("#div").load('arquivo.php');
    });
});
</script>
<input type="button" id="button">
<div id="div"></div>
```

Exemplo de código que não funciona:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(function() 
{
var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

var upload = $('form').ajaxForm(
{
    beforeSend: function() 
    {
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) 
    {
        //aumenta barra de progresso
    },
    complete: function(xhr) 
    {
    }
});
});
</script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="formSendTorrent"    name="formSendTorrent">
    <input type="file" multiple name="inputfileSendTorrent[]"       id="inputfileSendTorrent"> 
    <input type="submit" name="submitSendTorrent" value="Enviar">
</form>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submitSendTorrent']))
{      
header('Location: index.php');
} 
?>
```

Comment: Que conteúdo você tem nesse arquivo em que quer dar o include ? é algo muito extenso ou pouca coisa? Pois poderia criar um arquivo .PHP que retornasse um JSON e fazer uma requisição em AJAX e montar o conteúdo no seu arquivo HTML

Comment: Nesse arquivo tem JS, HTML e PHP, uma pagina inteira que eu chamo dentro de uma DIV. Alterei a pergunta.

Comment: Teoricamente esta certo. "além de alguns elementos não funcionarem" ele chega  a carregar o arquivo então  ?ou carrega mas sem todas as funções ?

Comment: Por exemplo, eu tenho um código em que quando você faz Upload de um arquivo o JS pega a porcentagem e depois ele deveria continuar a executar o PHP, esse código funciona perfeitamente, porem quando uso o `load` ele não executa o PHP que esta em baixo.

Comment: Poderia descrever um pouco mais sobre o problema?

Comment: @Matheus O ultimo código que eu coloquei na pergunta, quando eu uso `include 'arquivo.php'` ele carrega o JS(carregando barra de upload), o HTML e o PHP(levando para a pagina home), porem quando eu carrego esse mesmo `arquivo.php` com o método `.load` do JS ele apenas consegue executar o JS e o HTML, o PHP acaba não sendo executado.

Comment: @LucasCarezia, você está executando esse HTML+JS num WebServer? Caso não, pode ser a razão de não executar o php no .load...

Comment: Passei pelo mesmo problema e resolvi incluindo o arquivo que deveria ser incluido no php direto no index. Assim todos os elementos carregados pelo .load() funcionarão.
Achei aqui a resposta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30092127/jquery-load-and-php-include

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível incluir um arquivo php dentro do javascript, pois o mesmo trabalha na maquina local do usuário, enquanto que o php funciona no servidor, que é interpretado e enviado para o navegador em formato html.

Uma solução pro seu problema é usar ajax. O ajax consegue enviar informações para o php rodando no servidor sem recarregar a tela, tornando possível executar funções que não seriam possíveis localmente.

Dê uma olhada neste artigo explicando o básico sobre o mesmo: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

> AJAX is a developer's dream, because you can:
>
> • Update a web page without reloading the page Request data from a server
>   • after the page has loaded Receive data from a server
>   • after the page has loaded Send data to a server - in the background

Ajax é o sonho dos desenvolvedores pois você pode:
Atualizar uma página sem recarrega-la com dados do servidor. Receber dados após o carregamento da página. Enviar dados em segundo plano após o carregamento da página.